# Necesito encontrar la instancia de un atributo de un objeto que se encuentra en un array para imprimirlo

Tags: java, array

tengo que encontrar la instancia Motorola del atributo marcaCelular de Cliente. Se encuentra en un switch dentro de un for. Sí, es un gran lio el flujo de control pero se me ocurrió así. Gracias de antemano.
El ejercicio es este: nombre y cedula del primer cliente en adquirir un motorola.

```
package principal1;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import recursos.Cliente;

public class Principal1 {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader in =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int opc=0;
    double ventasLG=0.0;
    int ventasKyocera=0;
    String nombre="";
    Cliente clientes[]=new Cliente[5];


    for (int i = 0; i < clientes.length; i++) {

        clientes[i] = new Cliente(nombre);

        String marcaCelular="";
        int celular=0;

        System.out.println("Ingrese marca del celular:\n1.-Nokia\n2.-Motorola"
                + "\n3.-LG\n4.-Kyocera");
        celular=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        switch(celular){
            case 1:
                clientes[i].setMarcaCelular("Nokia");
                System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del cliente");
                nombre=in.readLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese cedula de identidad");
                int cedulaIdentidad=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                System.out.println("Ingrese precio del celular");
                int precioCelular=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                clientes[i]=new Cliente(nombre, cedulaIdentidad, marcaCelular, precioCelular);
                  break;
            case 2:
                clientes[i].setMarcaCelular("Motorola");
                System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del cliente");
                nombre=in.readLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese cedula de identidad");
                cedulaIdentidad=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                System.out.println("Ingrese precio del celular");
                precioCelular=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                clientes[i]=new Cliente(nombre, cedulaIdentidad, marcaCelular, precioCelular);

                break;
            case 3:
                clientes[i].setMarcaCelular("LG");
                System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del cliente");
                nombre=in.readLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese cedula de identidad");
                cedulaIdentidad=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                System.out.println("Ingrese precio del celular");
                precioCelular=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                clientes[i]=new Cliente(nombre, cedulaIdentidad, marcaCelular, precioCelular);
                //2
                ventasLG++;
                break;
            case 4:
                clientes[i].setMarcaCelular("Kyocera");
                System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del cliente");
                nombre=in.readLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese cedula de identidad");
                cedulaIdentidad=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                System.out.println("Ingrese precio del celular");
                precioCelular=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                if(precioCelular>=300000){
                ventasKyocera++;
                }
                clientes[i]=new Cliente(nombre, cedulaIdentidad, marcaCelular, precioCelular);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Opcion incorrecta");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para saber cuales de los clientes tienen motorola basta con poner suponinedo q tengan getters `if(clientes[i].getMarcaCelular.equal("Motorola"))` dentro de un `While` para cuando lo encuentre dentro del arreglo de cliente sepas cual es la primera. Deberia de quedarte asi suponiendo q tengas los getters y lo demas lo adaptas a tu codigo

```
boolean flag=true;
int i=0;
While(flag==true){
   if(clientes[i].getMarcaCelular.equal("Motorola"){
      System.out.println(clientes[i].getNombre()+ "Cedula"+ clientes[i].getCedula());
      flag=false;
   }
   i++;   
}
```

Comment: Hice lo que me dijiste pero no me funciono, ni siquiera imprime algo. Creo que tengo problemas con el equals, utilizo el equals y el equalsIgnoreCase pero no funciona